# HP PSC 1500 test page

Tags: printer, calibration

I just got a HP PSC 1500 with color cartridge empty. Is there a way to stop these test pages without buying color ink to print 1 page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the look of it, this seems to be a very difficult thing to stop -

> I am no computer boff. however I have discovered that this happens if your printer cartridge expiry date has passed.
>   The only way to stop it is to have your finger hover over the cancel/resume button and immediately it starts to print the test page, press the button to abort the print. you can then proceed as normal.

[Source](http://forums11.itrc.hp.com/service/forums/questionanswer.do?admit=109447626%201308307140358%2028353475&threadId=1136732)